# How to toggle developer modal on an iOS simulatorin mac-in-cloud?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, emulation, mac-in-cloud

I'm using an iOS simulator in [mac-in-cloud](https://www.macincloud.com/) (a mac in browser service).

I'd like to toggle the developer modal (like it's doing with ctrl+m on my Android emulator).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `Hardware` menu at the top of the Mac desktop, and select `Shake gesture` while your app is running on the iOS Simulator:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

[image: Opening the React Native developer menu on the iOS Simulator]